# Same store information returning in multi-store in observer Magento

Tags: magento, locale, observers, multistore

I have a multi-store website, I am developing a module in which I need to get locale or store id in observer when I edit product from wishlist and add to cart. But it returns the same locale and store id from both stores. I am using the below in my observer.

```
 Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
 Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
```

Can you please suggest me what can be the issue?

Comment: Why is that `die` there?

Comment: it was just to see what it returns in observer.

Comment: which event are you observing?

Comment: controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_cart

Comment: do you get the product object in this event observer?

Comment: no i am geting the wishlist product collection in this